Enable a GitHub branch protection rule that can be overridden by force, but only intentionally
I would like to create a GitHub branch-protection rule that I can override, but only intentionally.
Currently, I can protect a branch with a rule (e.g., "Require a pull request before merging") and I can also allow specific users to be able to bypass this rule (via "Allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests"). However, in this case a simple git push is all that is required to bypass the rule if I am on the whitelist of actors. This is too easy to do accidentally. I would like to still allow myself to bypass the rule, but to only be able to do so intentionally (e.g., via git push --force).
I've tried using "Do not allow bypassing the above settings", but if I am added to this list of "Allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests" this doesn't help. I've also tried using the "Allow force pushes" toggles, but they don't help me either.

Unfortunately, GitHub branch protection rules don't currently offer a way to bypass them intentionally with an extra step like git push --force.
